# Ionic 2 Need to update Arrow position of button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Normally, If we use button, Arrow will present on the right side. It will point towards right... ie., Arrow position.

I need to change the arrow position to downwards. How can i proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the icon to buttons with `ion-icon` and pass a name of icon in `name` 
 attribute in it

```
<ion-buttons>
      <button ion-button>
        <ion-icon name="arrow-down"></ion-icon> Hello
      </button>
</ion-buttons>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 <ion-icon name="arrow-down"></ion-icon>
```

you can see the arrow is pointing downwards